# Собрать ссылки со страницы с использованием фильтров с помощью selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Мне нужно спарсить список ссылок на видео ютуб используя запрос который мне нужен и фильтр

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time 

name = 'hello world'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
id_serth = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search_query")
id_serth.send_keys(name)
button_serth = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-icon-legacy")
time.sleep(1)
button_serth.click()
time.sleep(3)
button_filtr = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME ,"ytd-toggle-button-renderer")
button_filtr.click()
time.sleep(3)
button_filtrtode=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ytd-search-filter-renderer")
button_filtrtode.click()


#linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "video-title").get_attribute("href")
time.sleep(3)

urltek = driver.current_url

linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]').get_attribute('href')


print (linkvideo2)
print (urltek)
```

Получаю ответ None

p.s только не давно начал изучать selenium не бейте)

```
None
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hello+world&sp=EgIIAQ%253D%253D
```

Answer (score 0):

В строке:

```
linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]').get_attribute('href')`
```

в XPATH вместо `//*[@id="video-title"]` поставьте `//a[@id="video-title"]`.

Тогда вы будете получать в переменную `linkvideo2` ссылку на самое верхнее видео. Ну а чтобы получить все ссылки можно сделать цикл.

Например:

```
videos_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@id="video-title"]')
for video in videos_list:
    print(video.get_attribute('href'))
```

Только учитывайте, что это будут не все видео по вашему запросу, а только те, которые в данный момент отображаются на странице.